# Why does parse_qs give different result depending on the way wsgi application has been started?

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I use Python 3.2.5 and Oracle Linux 6.4. I have written my wsgi application but I have some trouble: function urllib.parse.parse_qs behave differently depending on the way I started my application (Apache with mod_wsgi or wsgiref.simple_server). In my `application` function I have the following code:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    print(environ["QUERY_STRING"])
    requestParams = parse_qs(environ["QUERY_STRING"])
    print(requestParams)
    .......
```

So. When I start my program using wsgiref.simple_server and make a query `/query?name=Иван` (it's Russian name) I get the following output:

```
name=%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD
{'name': ['Иван']}
```

But my application with Apache + mod_wsgi gives me the following:

```
name=%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD
{'name': ['\xd0\x98\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd']}
```

As you can see, the latter doesn't give me correct Russian word encoded in UTF-8 although the input to the function is the same. According to https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html function parse_qs has default parameter encoding='utf-8'. As a result I have other problems during further work. I can't understand why this function works differently.

I have the following Apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_project
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/my_project/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess my_project processes=8 threads=1 python-path=/var/www/my_project display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup my_project
    WSGIScriptAlias /my_project /var/www/my_project/my_project.py
</VirtualHost>
```

My apache uses prefork MPM.

Answer (score 0):

Graham Dumpleton (one of the developers of mod_wsgi) suggested me to use `lang=en_US.UTF-8 locale=en_US.UTF-8` in `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive. These options aren't described in docs but they helped me to overcome my problems with string although python's `print` function doesn't print proper string. It still prints `\xd0\x98\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd` in Apache log. But writing to a file works well. Therefore I can assume that it's because the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING` is not set for my python script which is started under Apache + mod_wsgi. Hope that my answer to my question will help someone.